# Query Documents that has type reference in Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

According to [Cloud Firestore=>Data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) Documentation, type `reference` act as foreign key in NoSQL world. but when I query it in Fluter/Dart. 
Database in Firestore.

**[Collection]**

Note: *DocumentOne's* data type are all `reference`

1. CollectionWithReference

   - DocumentOne

     - FKOne/doc001
     - FKTwo/doc002
2. FKOne

   - doc001

     - "someData": 'Just Some Data'
3. FKTwo

   - doc002

     - "anotherData": 'Just Another Data'

**Example Code:**

```
Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionWithReference').snapshots()
  .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((document) => print(document.data)));
```

**Output**

> {FKOne: Instance of 'DocumentReference', FKTwo: [Instance of 'DocumentReference', Instance of 'DocumentReference', Instance of 'DocumentReference']}

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: as the title says, I want to query the data of the reference in that document, but it gives me the `Instance of 'DocumentReference'`. I'm trying to deal with this problem now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output in your question is *to be expected*.
Because your ***references*** are parsed as **objects**, `print` will only print out `Instance of 'DocumentReference'`.

[Here you can take a look at the class `DocumentReference`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart), which contains all the necessary data about your reference.
In the following code I will print out the `path` (which is a getter of every `DocumentReference` object) of each of your references:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionWithReference').snapshots().listen((data) {
  data.documents.forEach((document) {
      print(document.data['FKOne'].path);
      document.data['FKTwo'].forEach((documentReference) => print(documentReference.path));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't do intensive search on how Firestore works with flutter, I was relying on the Intellisense provided by DartCode in Visual Studio Code. it didn't pop out `path`.

Comment: @Clueless Because it cannot know the type of your data. **You** specify the data type of your data. If you want code suggestions, you can do the following: `document.data['FKOne'] as DocumentReference`.

Comment: How to handle this on nestjs?